Can I find a string within a file name and delete that string in VBA?
I am working within a quality system, and I work off of a redlined document (microsoft word). When I go to upload it into our system, I need to upload the redlined version (it says "redlines" in the filename), and then a clean copy and a pdf copy. I have recorded a macro that does everything except changing the file name. Is it possible to search for the word "redlines" in the file name, delete that word, then save it as a new file? This is what I have so far. For example, if my redlined version is called "My File Redlines.docx" I would want it to save the file as "My File.docx". The filename can vary in length, and the location of the word "redlines" can also vary, so it can't be based upon a fixed location.
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    ActiveDocument.Save
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _
        **Need help how to do this part. I want to remove the word "Redlines" from the file name**, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = Not ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions
    ActiveDocument.AcceptAllRevisions
    ActiveDocument.Save
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        **This will have the same file name as above, but saved as a PDF** _
        , ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
End Sub



Using multiple replacement to get the desired file name
Set Compare:=vbTextCompare to make the replacement case-insensitive.

Microsoft documentation:

Replace function

Sub Macro1()
    Dim sFile As String, sPath As String, aTxt
    sFile = ActiveDocument.Name ' get doc name
    sPath = ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator ' get path
    sFile = Replace(sFile, "redlines", "", Compare:=vbTextCompare) ' remove redlines
    sFile = Replace(sFile, "  ", " ", Compare:=vbTextCompare) ' remove dumplicate space
    sFile = Replace(sFile, " .doc", ".doc", Compare:=vbTextCompare) ' remove extra space before .
    Debug.Print sPath & sFile
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=sPath & sFile, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = Not ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions
    ActiveDocument.AcceptAllRevisions
    ActiveDocument.Save
    aTxt = Split(sFile, ".")
    aTxt(UBound(aTxt)) = "pdf" ' replace extention name with pdf, compatible for *.doc*
    sFile = Join(aTxt, ".")
    Debug.Print sPath & sFile
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=sPath & sFile, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
End Sub



KoldBeans!
I suggest you create a function like this:
Function RemoveRedlines(ByVal sFileName As String) As String

    Dim retVal As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    
    retVal = Replace(sFileName, "Redlines", "", 1)  ' Removes 'Readlines' from file name
    pos = InStr(1, retVal, ".", vbTextCompare)      ' Gets '.' position into new file name string
    retVal = Trim(Mid(retVal, 1, pos - 1))          ' Joins trimmed string to file extention
    RemoveRedlines = retVal                         ' Passes 'retVal' as function result

End Function

To use it, add this code into your subroutine:
Sub Macro1()
    Dim NewFileName As String
    NewFileName = RemoveRedlines("My File Redlines.docx")  ' Replace "My File Readlines.docx" with your variable name;

    ' Replace ellipsis with your parameters for docx file
    ActiveDocument.Save ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _
    NewFileName & ".docx", (...)

    ' Replace ellipsis with your parameters for pdf file
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= := _
    NewFileName & ".pdf", (...)

End Sub

Note: I haven't included any handling for malformed filenames or errors.

Backup Active Document
Sub BackupDocument()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const DELETE_STRING As String = "Redlines"
    ' The following two have to be in 'sync'.
    Const DST_FILE_EXTENSION As String = ".docx"
    Const DST_FILE_FORMAT As Long = wdFormatXMLDocument
    
    ' Reference and save the active document.

    Dim doc As Document
    On Error Resume Next
        Set doc = ActiveDocument
    On Error GoTo 0

    If doc Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no active document!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If doc Is ThisDocument Then
        MsgBox "Cannot perform this operation on the workbook " _
            & "containing this code """ & ThisDocument.Name & """!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = doc.Name
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = doc.Path
    
    If Len(sFolderPath) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file """ & sFileName & """ was never saved!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not doc.Saved Then doc.Save ' save the original
    
    ' Build the destination file base path, the path without the file extension.
    
    Dim sFileBaseName As String:
    sFileBaseName = Left(sFileName, InStrRev(sFileName, ".") - 1)
    
    If InStr(1, sFileBaseName, DELETE_STRING, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file name """ & sFileName _
            & """ doesn't contain the substring """ & DELETE_STRING _
            & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dFileBaseName As String:
    dFileBaseName = Replace(sFileBaseName, DELETE_STRING, "", , , vbTextCompare)
    
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = sFolderPath ' or something else?
    
    Dim dFileBasePath As String:
    dFileBasePath = dFolderPath & Application.PathSeparator & dFileBaseName
    
    ' Backup file.
    
    With doc
        ' At this moment, 'doc' is still the initial file.
        .TrackRevisions = Not .TrackRevisions
        .AcceptAllRevisions
        Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
        ' The previous line means e.g. overwrite without confirmation,
        ' don't alert if different file format, ...
            .SaveAs2 FileName:=dFileBasePath & DST_FILE_EXTENSION, _
                FileFormat:=DST_FILE_FORMAT, LockComments:=False, _
                Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", _
                ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
                SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, _
                SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
        Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
        ' At this moment, 'doc' is the new file.
        .ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=dFileBasePath & ".pdf", _
            ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, _
            OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
            From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
            IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
            CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
            DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
            UseISO19005_1:=False
        '.FollowHyperlink dFolderPath ' explore the folder path?
        '.Close SaveChanges:=False ' the new file just got saved!
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Backups of the file """ & sFileName & """ created!", vbInformation
    
End Sub

